# Limit what Type’s can be passed to method through interface

Tags: c#, reflection, interface

How to pass a type into a method that inherits a specific interface.

Example

I have an interface

```
public interface iBase
{
    void DoWork(object t);

}
```

I have a class that implements the interface

```
public class WorkerClass : iBase
{
    public void DoWork(object t)
    {

    }
}
```

The following code uses the 2 classes above

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Start(typeof(WorkerClass));
    }

    public static void Start(Type type)
    {
        iBase workerClass = (iBase)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        workerClass.DoWork("tst");
    }
}
```

The above code works, but I want to make it so the Start's input parameter (Type type) only accepts type’s that are inherited from iBase. At present "type" will accept any type which is not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Start<WorkerClass>();
    }

    public static void Start<T>() where T : iBase
    {
        iBase workerClass = (iBase)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

        workerClass.DoWork("tst");
    }
}
```

Even better would be if you could remove the reflection by ensuring that your type has a public parameterless constructor at compile time:

```
    public static void Start<T>() where T : iBase, new()
    {
        var instance = new T();

        instance.DoWork("tst");
    }
```

Comment: +1 for the `new()` constraint. Didn't want to add this in the first place since I wasn't sure if this works for structs, too. It does.

Answer (score 3):

You can use generics to do that:

```
public static void Start<T>() where T : iBase
{
    iBase workerClass = (iBase)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

    workerClass.DoWork("tst");
}
```

`T` is the generic type parameter and the `where` constraint makes sure that only types that implement `iBase` are accepted.
The `typeof` operator is used to get a `Type` instance for the specified type.

You can call it like that:

```
Start<WorkerClass>();
```

with `WorkerClass` being the generic type argument.

---

Further reading on generics:

- [An Introduction to C# Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms379564(v=vs.80))
- [Generics (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/index)